# PHP fork, and get result from child

Tags: php, linux, fork, simultaneous-calls

I need a routine to make 2 or more dns requests at the same time, but only use the first/fastest result.

How do i return the answar from the child's so i only get one result ?

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) die("could not fork");

if ($pid) {

  //parent

} else { 

  $pid2 = pcntl_fork(); 

  if ($pid2 == -1) die("could not fork"); 

  if ($pid2) {

    //parent-child

    exec("/usr/bin/dig @8.8.8.8 $name A +short +time=1+tries=1",$ips_array,$digreturn);

  } else {

    exec("/usr/bin/dig @8.8.4.4 $name A +short +time=1 +tries=1",$ips_array,$digreturn);

  }

}

print_r ($ips_array);
```

This will return 2 times the answer, if both requests are returned

Comment: When you fork, each process has its own copies of all variables, including `$ips_array()`. You need to use a pipe to communicate results back to the original parent process, which can merge them together.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a look at **socket_create_pair()**. 
In the PHP manual is a very short & easy example of interprocess communication (IPC) between a fork()-parent and the child.
Abd using serialize() und unserialize() You could even transfer complex data types like arrays...